# Unicode problem when using cppimport/pybind11

Tags: c++11, unicode, pycharm, pybind11

I am trying to use cppimport, an lib based on pybind11, to import some *.cpp files directly into python, according to the author's [example](https://github.com/tbenthompson/cppimport).

I am using Pycharm and python 3.7, installed both cppimport and pybind11, win10.
The import code is quite easy using cppimport.

```
import cppimport.import_hook
import DemoTrade
```

Then I got an error

```
mako.exceptions.CompileException: Unicode decode operation of encoding 'ascii' failed in file 'C:\Users\...\DemoTrade.cpp' at line: 0 char: 0
```

The files address is right, otherwise it will give another error

The problem seems in the coding of files, I changed other encoding, but nothing improved.
I don't know how to deal with this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since cppimport is based on pybind11 and mako,  this is a mako problem.

in cppimport lib, find templating.py.

Then add the encode you want in mako.template.Template(). Following is an example

```
mako.template.Template(filename = filepath, lookup = lookup,
                      input_encoding='gb2312', output_encoding='gb2312')
```

Then it is solved.